# Vba Macro that addes new column then change the cells into time format

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA macro excel.... the macro created adds a new column named "Response Time" then it subtracts 2 columns namely "Find Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_actual" and "Full Out Gate at Inland or Interim Point (Destination)_recvd" and put the subtraction (output) value in that new columned named Response time...
Macro is executing properly, however, the newly added column i.e. "Response Time" should be in "HH:MM:SS" format here the output is showing weird. So am trying to fix the newly added column cells format in "hh:mm:ss" format.... I will paste the code below and also the excel screen for ref

[![Response Time][1]][1]

In the above screenshot, Macro has created column "Response Time and subtracted column L2-K2... However, the output in column M shows "1/0/1900" which is weird wherein I want to see the only output as "6:21"

Comment: Did you just mean to use `cl.Offset(1, 1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"`, without `Cells`?

Comment: I just tried that coding since cl denotes to be the new column name so i just thought I am not sure since I am new to this macros

Comment: `cl` is not the new column name. It is a `Range`.

Comment: ohh then how can I format the newly added column in "hh:mm:ss" format

Comment: `cl.Offset(,1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"` maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to format the entire column, then perhaps:

```
cl.Offset(,1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
```